# django template tag error: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering

Tags: django

I'm trying to use the url template tag here but it gives me the

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /pastebin/pastes/

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'pastebin_paste_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Everything looks correct to me and the second I remove the template tag, the template renders perfectly fine.  And the `pastebin_paste_detail` generic view itself works fine too.  Is this some sort of syntax issue?  Or does the template tag not work in django 1.3?

Here's the template:

```
    <title>Paste List</title>
</head>
<body>

{% if object_list %}
    <h1>Paste List</h1>
<ul>
    {% for obj in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url pastebin_paste_detail paste.id %}">{{ obj }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
    <h1>No recent pastes</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Here's the urlconf:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from models import Paste

paste_info = {
        'queryset': Paste.objects.all(),
        }


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # basically this generic view creates a form based on the specified model
    url(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.create_update.create_object', { 'model': Paste }),
    url(r'^paste/(?P<object_id>\d+)$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', paste_info, name='pastebin_paste_detail'),
    url(r'^pastes/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', paste_info),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that you're passing paste.id - but there isn't a "paste" object?

pass obj.id instead XD

This is identified by it showing the argument as `('',)` (nothing being passed in).

As your urlconf uses named args for the parameter, you may want to use named args here too

```
{% url pastebin_paste_detail object_id=obj.id %}
```